Blazor looses reference to InteractiveServer
If I use the default blazor template setting the interactive mode to Server on project creation, then when I press F5 all works.
I dont like the folder layout of :
Components/Pages
I want to move the Pages folder to the same level as components, so that I can use the Components Folder for my own components and thus keep the structure more meaningful.
When I move my Pages folder and all pages up a level suddenly :
@page "/counter"
@rendermode InteractiveServer

the InteractiveServer redlines in VS. I've been searching for ages but cannot figure out why it is doing this. Any help greatly appreciated.

Hi @bilpor, _Imports.razor works for the current folder. You could just move it to the root project which will resolve your issue.


I dont like the folder layout of :  Components/Pages

But that did have the benefit of sharing the Components/_Imports.razor file

When I move my Pages folder and all pages up a level

After that the files in the Pages folder no longer have access to the shared usings.
The quick fix is one of:

Copy the _Imports.razor file to the Pages folder, or
Move the _Imports.razor file to the root of the project.

_Imports is only used by .razor files, not by .cs files. Moving it to the root is probably the best option with the least maintenance issues.

Cant believe I missed that. THank you.
